# Text extraction from multiple webpages (URLs in a text file)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

(Environment: Python 2.7 + BeautifulSoup 4.3.2)

I am using Python and BeautifulSoup to pick up the news titles on this webpage and its subsequent pages. I don’t know how to have it automatically follow the subsequent/next pages so I put all the URLs in a text file, web list.txt.

```
http://www.legaldaily.com.cn/locality/node_32245.htm
http://www.legaldaily.com.cn/locality/node_32245_2.htm
http://www.legaldaily.com.cn/locality/node_32245_3.htm
```

.
.
.

Here’s what I worked out so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2
import urllib


list_open = open("web list.txt")
read_list = list_open.read()
line_in_list = read_list.split("\n")


i = 0
while i < len(line_in_list):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read(), 'html')
    news_list = soup.find_all(attrs={'class': "f14 blue001"})
    for news in news_list:
        print news.getText()
i + = 1
```

It pops up an error message saying there’s an invalid syntax.

What went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i + = 1
```

This is invalid syntax.

If you want to use the augmented assignment operator `+=`, you can't have a space between the plus and the equals.

```
i += 1
```

The next error you'll get is:

```
NameError: name 'url' is not defined
```

Because you never define `url` before you use it in the `soup =` line. You can fix this by iterating directly over the url list, instead of incrementing `i` at all.

```
for url in line_in_list:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read(), 'html')
    news_list = soup.find_all(attrs={'class': "f14 blue001"})
    for news in news_list:
        print news.getText()
```

Comment: thanks Kevin. it solves the problem. however when the running ends, it shows a pile or error messages. i put them on http://pastie.org/8655927. what's that about? tks

Comment: I don't get that error on my machine. I'm guessing you have an empty line in your `web list.txt` file.

Comment: Kevin you are right. seems i need to figure out the way of putting the urls in the text file. have a nice day!